# Detect when a UIViewController has been dismissed by the remote's menu button in tvOS

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, tvos, dismiss

I am working on a **Apple TV app (tvOS)** where the **first view controller** open a **second view controller** via a **segue**. When I choose an option on the second view controller it execute an unwind action on the first view controller.

My problem is when I press the **remote menu button**, the **second view controller modal dismiss automatically** and I find no way to execute an action on the first view controller or to be notified.

How can I detect when a controller opened via a segue has been dissmissed by the **remote's menu button** ?

```
┌─────────────┐               ┌─────────────┐   
│ First View  │    ┌─────┐    │ Modal View  ├──┐
│ Controller  ├────┤segue├────▶ Controller  │  │
└─────────────┘    └─────┘    └─────────────┘  │
                ┌────────────┐      ┌───────┐  │
                │ Modal Auto │      │ Menu  │  │
  Action ??  ◀──┤  Dismiss   ◀──────│Button │◀─┘
                └────────────┘      └───────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to accomplish

```
// Put this in your FirstViewController
@IBAction func returnToFirstViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
  print("This is called after  modal is dismissed by menu button on Siri Remote")
}

// Put this in your SecondViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()  

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

  let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleMenuPress:"))
  tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [UIPressType.Menu.rawValue]
  view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

func handleMenuPress(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("YourUnwindSegueIdentifier", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
  if segue.identifier == "YourUnwindSegueIdentifier" {
     // do any cleanup activities here if you need
  }
}
```

Now you have to make some  storyboard connections.   Go into your SecondViewController and ctrl-drag from your Controller icon to your Exit icon and you'll see a drop down like this:

[image]

Select the method to connect it and then you'll see an Unwind Segue in your SecondViewController in the storyboard.   Give that segue the identifier name of "YourUnwindSegueIdentifier" (so my sample code will work - or use whatever name you want).   Build and run and this should get you what you need.

Comment: Pressing the menu button of the remote dismiss automatically the modal view controller and return to the parent view controller (linked via a segue). I want to execute an action when it dismiss the second view controller. It's like the back button on a navigation controller...

Comment: So you "want" the second view controller to go away and then do an action inside the first view controller?

Comment: The second view controller dismiss alone automatically, and yes I want to intercept to make an action on the first view controller.

Comment: I've updated my answer to support your use case.. hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I passed many time to find a way to be notified that I didn't think about adding an storyboard's action to the menu button... ;)

Comment: How can I send you an App Store coupon code to download my app for the help ?

Answer (score 0):

**First view controller:**

```
@IBAction func modalDismissed(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("Modal dismissed")
}
```

**Modal view controller:**

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    for item in presses {
        if item.type == .Menu {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("dismissModal", sender: nil)
        }
    }
    super.pressesBegan(presses, withEvent: event)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "dismissModal" {
        print("Modal Dismiss")
    }
}
```

Create **an exit segue** on modal view controller named *"dismissModal"*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the what worked for me using Swift 5:

```
private func setupRemoteGesture() {
    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleMenuPress))
    tapRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPress.PressType.menu.rawValue)]
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

@objc private func handleMenuPress() {
    // Menu button pressed
}
```